# Mule 4.2.2 upgrade: Error No value present MULE:SOURCE_RESPONSE_SENDorg.mule.extension.db.api.StatementResult

Tags: mulesoft

From Mule ee 4.1.4 to 4.2.2

```
ERROR 2020-10-13 05:48:41,099 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.05: [pcl-data-convert-service].post:\v1\masterdata:application\json:pcl-data-convert-service-config.CPU_LITE @45774113] [event: 658be040-asfl-lkio-dhn8i-7865b9aghyji] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : No value present.
Element               : pcl-data-convert-service-main/source @ pcl-data-convert-service:pcl-data-convert-service.xml:7 (Listener-HTTPS)
Element XML           : <http:listener config-ref="pcl-data-convert-service-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="Listener-HTTPS">
                        <http:response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 200]"></http:response>
                        <http:error-response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 500]">
                        <http:body>#[payload]</http:body>
                        </http:error-response>
                        </http:listener>
Error type            : MULE:SOURCE_RESPONSE_SEND
Payload Type          : org.mule.extension.db.api.StatementResult
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext.getDefaultErrorHandler(DefaultMuleContext.java:868)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.client.MuleClientFlowConstruct.getExceptionListener(MuleClientFlowConstruct.java:60)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.event.DefaultEventContext.<init>(DefaultEventContext.java:159)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.event.EventContextFactory.create(EventContextFactory.java:87)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.event.EventContextFactory.create(EventContextFactory.java:46)
    at (more) .....
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a problem in one of the cumulative patches. Try with the latest cumulative patch applied. If in CloudHub try to update to the last release for your version.